# App bundling field - Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/ColorPropType.js`

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

The app is making this error - after executing react-native run-android command

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module
>   `react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/ColorPropType.js` from
>   `/Users/mohsen/Desktop/roam -
>   native/roam/node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/index.android.js`:
>   Module `react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/ColorPropType.js` does not
>   exist in the Haste module map

Comment: Which versions of react-native and react-native-linear-gradient  are you using?

Comment: I'm having the same issue for react native windows...

Comment: Please post if you found any solution